# How to custom-sort a list of dict to use in json.dumps

Tags: python, json, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list similar to

```
allsites = [
    {
        'A5': 'G', 
        'A10': 'G', 
        'site': 'example1.com', 
        'A1': 'G'
    }, 
    {
        'A5': 'R', 
        'A10': 'Y',
        'site': 'example2.com', 
        'A1': 'G'
    }
]
```

Which I use in a `json.dumps`:

```
data = { 'Author':"joe", 'data':allsites }
print json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

This outputs the following JSON:

```
{
    "Author": "joe",
    "data": [
        {
            "A1": "G",
            "A10": "G",
            "A5": "G",
            "site": "example1.com"
        },
        {
            "A1": "G",
    (...)
```

I would like the "data" section of this JSON string to be sorted via a custom key ("alphabet"), in the case above this would be `site, A1, A5, A10` and actually look like:

```
{
    "Author": "joe",
    "data": [
        {
            "site": "example1.com",
            "A1": "G",
            "A5": "G",
            "A10": "G"
        },
        {
            "site": "example2.com",
            "A1": "G",
    (...)
```

I read about custom sorting in the [Sorting FAQ](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) but it just gives a way to override the comparison function, not to mention that I do not know how to insert this into my code.

How to do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since python dicts are unordered collections, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with a custom sort:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

allsites = [
    {
        'A5': 'G',
        'A10': 'G',
        'site': 'example1.com',
        'A1': 'G'
    },
    {
        'A5': 'R',
        'A10': 'Y',
        'site': 'example2.com',
        'A1': 'G'
    }
]

sort_order = ['site', 'A1', 'A5', 'A10']
allsites_ordered = [OrderedDict(sorted(item.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): sort_order.index(k)))
                    for item in allsites]

data = {'Author': "joe", 'data': allsites_ordered}
print json.dumps(data, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

prints:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "site": "example1.com",
            "A1": "G",
            "A5": "G",
            "A10": "G"
        },
        {
            "site": "example2.com",
            "A1": "G",
            "A5": "R",
            "A10": "Y"
        }
    ],
    "Author": "joe"
}
```

Comment: Don't work more for python3, @alecxe, it say: "tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in python 3". See Scott Answer.

Answer (score 20):

In Python3, alecxe's answer no longer works. This should be a comment, but I lack the reputation.

[PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) removed tuple unpacking in function signatures, so the line

```
allsites_ordered = [OrderedDict(sorted(item.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): sort_order.index(k)))
                    for item in allsites]
```

now has to be

```
allsites_ordered = [OrderedDict(sorted(item.items(), key=lambda item: sort_order.index(item[0])))
                    for item in allsites]
```

or similar. `iteritems` has also become just `items`.

Comment: And in Python 3.6, the dict is now ordered by default.  That is, it works and somehow we shouldn't "plan on it working".

Comment: @CharlesMerriam Agreed. There's a bit of absurdity surrounding dictionary ordering at the moment. The biggest issue, I suppose, is that non-CPython implementations of the language might not have "gotten things in order yet" so to speak.

Comment: Small update: as of Python 3.7, the `dict` is ordered by default and we *can* count on it--it's become part of the spec. There still is an argument to be made for using an `OrderedDict` as a semantic indicator that you're using the ordering property. Additionally, the `OrderedDict` keeps its extra `popitem()` and `move_to_end()` methods that the builtin `dict` still lacks. More details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872567/600882

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem and devised a lightweight general solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def make_custom_sort(orders):
    orders = [{k: -i for (i, k) in enumerate(reversed(order), 1)} for order in orders]
    def process(stuff):
        if isinstance(stuff, dict):
            l = [(k, process(v)) for (k, v) in stuff.items()]
            keys = set(stuff)
            for order in orders:
                if keys.issuperset(order):
                    return OrderedDict(sorted(l, key=lambda x: order.get(x[0], 0)))
            return OrderedDict(sorted(l))
        if isinstance(stuff, list):
            return [process(x) for x in stuff]
        return stuff
    return process
```

First, you create an instance of a custom-order sorting function:

```
custom_sort = make_custom_sort([ ["site", "A1", "A5", "A10"] ])
```

Now, the actual sorting:

```
result = custom_sort(allsites)
```

... which you may dump as a JSON object:

```
print json.dumps(result, indent=4)
```

### Result

```
[
    {
        "site": "example1.com", 
        "A1": "G", 
        "A5": "G", 
        "A10": "G"
    }, 
    {
        "site": "example2.com", 
        "A1": "G", 
        "A5": "R", 
        "A10": "Y"
    }
]
```

### More

The closure is recursive. As indicated by the double brackets, you could specify as many sort orders as the various dictionaries nested in your structure would require.

Project on GitHub: https://github.com/laowantong/customsort